# Is Jean Grey the only person Toad has slimed?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

In Bryan Singer's first of the mutant movies, "X-Men", a scene in the Statue of Liberty depicts Toad spewing a thick green goo at Jean which hardens to her face, blocking off her air. Due to her powers at the time (low-level telekinesis and low-level telepathy), she was unable to affect the slime and had to wait for Cyclops to save her, using his optic beam to smash the slime.

Now, that happened back in 2000, and we are now nearing the end of 2015. So, my question is: has this happened with anyone else? Surely Jean Grey isn't the only person Toad has used this life-threatening ability on? I am accepting all answers, from any comic, film, or cartoon canon, and in or out of universe explanations.

Comment: "Is Jean Grey the only person Toad has slimed?" That's kind of personal, don't you think?

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, Jean Grey is the only person Toad has used his adhesive saliva on *in the Fox Movie Universe*.

In the comics, this is one of Toad's primary weapons, and he uses it quite a lot. Here, for example, he gives Wolverine a run for his money:

[image]

It's important to note that Toad's saliva works different in the movies than in the source comics. Earth-616 Toad's saliva isn't merely thick and adhesive, it's actually very acidic: if he spit it in someone's face, they wouldn't merely suffocate, it would begin to eat away at their skin and be very painful. But it also means he can use his saliva to dissolve inanimate objects (walls, doors, etc). This makes his saliva mutation a lot more utilitarian in the comics that it appears to be in the movies.

Comment: @KutuluMike-When you say that 616-Toad uses the slime quite a lot, does that mean you know of any others besides Jean Grey and Wolverine that he has slimed? Just curious.

Answer (score 4):

In *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, we catch up with Alex Summers in Vietnam. With him is Toad, now played by Evan Jonigkei.

[image]

Soon after, Mystique breaks in and starts kicking ass. In the ensuing brawl, Toad slimes a soldier.

Comment: -Which version of the movie were you watching? I watched both the original and Rogue Cut versions of the film, and the only thing that Toad did to a soldier was use his tongue to snatch their gun.